# How to handle image path for an image comming from external sources like Dropbox

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I've developed image cropper so that user can crop selected image from gallery. When user has taken a picture with camera or has selected it from gallery, image uri is queried for image metadata and image file path is passed to various bitmap methods for bitmap creation.

But now I've expanded users selection option to Dropbox also and uri that I receive from intent is in the form of:

```
01-08 09:11:21.051: I/DROPBOX(2761): file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u98667695/scratch/Capture.PNG
```

Query on this uri returns null for cursor, so I tried to convert uri to string, remove first 7 characters and pass that string as image file path. This works fine if I select image from root directory on Dropbox...

**So, my question how image request from external sources like Dropbox for instance in order to get image file path when intent returns uri for requested image?**

This is method where I'm retrieving file path:

```
    private void getImageData(Uri selectedImage){

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        String[] fileOrientationColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
/*      if(cursor == null){
            imageFilePath = selectedImage.toString().substring(6);
            return;
        }
*/      cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        imageFilePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        Log.i("CURSOR path", imageFilePath);

        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                fileOrientationColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(fileOrientationColumn[0]);
        String fileOrientation = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        // Izmena
        if(fileOrientation == null)fileOrientation = "0";

        imageOrientation = Integer.parseInt(fileOrientation);
        cursor.close();     

        Log.i("CURSOR orientation", fileOrientation);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In above case you can do the following.

```
String filePath="I/DROPBOX(2761): file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u98667695/scratch/Capture.PNG";
int firstIndex=filePath.indexOf("file");
String actualPath=filePath.subString(firstIndex);
```

So the actualPath contains required path as follows, irrespective of root directory or file location.

```
actualPath="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u98667695/scratch/Capture.PNG"
```

Comment: I am facing same problem , but i am getting this URI file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u209004291/scratch/Account_Customer_id.jpg

Still i am not able to get path and file name .. Please tell me what is solution of same ?